# Getting IMEI of a phone

Tags: android, xamarin.android, imei

I'm trying to retrieve the IMEI number of a phone. I'm using code below:

```
public static string GetDeviceId(Context context)
{
    TelephonyManager telephonyMgr = context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService) as TelephonyManager;
    string deviceId = telephonyMgr.DeviceId == null ? "UNAVAILABLE" : telephonyMgr.DeviceId;
    return deviceId;
}
```

Is there any problem with the code? What else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add the following permission in the *manifest file*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I forgot to add permission. However, .getDeviceId() did not work for me. Instead, my codes worked well. I also got deviceId by equilizing GetDeviceId to a string imeiNumber. Thanks again for quick answer.

Comment: What he wrote is when using Java for Android.